# CSSearchableItemAttributeSet init methods return nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some trouble with the new Core Spotlight API in iOS 9. The problem is that the init methods for CSSearchableItemAttributeSet returns nil. Here is an example that does not work for me:

```
CSSearchableItemAttributeSet* attributeSet = [[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] initWithItemContentType:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage];

attributeSet.title = movie.movieName;
attributeSet.contentDescription = movie.shortDescription ? movie.shortDescription : movie.longDescription;
attributeSet.thumbnailURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [movie posterURLStringWithWidth:100]];
```

the attributeSet is nil directly from start, so the last three lines does nothing. I have added the CoreSpotlight and MobileCoreService framework to the project and imported them in the same file. I have tried `[[CSSearchableItemAttributeSet alloc] init]` and this as well returns nil. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Using Xcode 7.0 beta 4. Any idea why it would return nil is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From some trying back and forth I realised I did not have an iOS 9 beta installed on my phone which kind of explains why iOS 9 features does not work.. So, to answer my own question, you need to install iOS 9 (beta) when using CoreSpotlight.